# How to prove that the function $\lambda \mapsto \langle T_{\lambda}f; g\rangle$ is holomorphic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, operator-theory

Let $\langle;\rangle$ be the usual  scalar product on $L^2(\Bbb R^2)$.
How to prove that the function $\lambda \mapsto \langle T_{\lambda}f; g\rangle$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C^+_*=\{z\in\Bbb C:\text{Re}(z)>0\}$ where
$f,g\in L^2(\Bbb R^2)$ and

$T_{\lambda}f(x,y)= \int_{\Bbb R^2}f(x-u,y-v) \psi\left(  \frac{\lambda-\mu}{2\lambda},1,\frac{\lambda}{2}(u^2+v^2)\right) e^{-\frac{\lambda}{4}\ (u^2+v^2\ ) - i\frac{\lambda}{2} (yu-xv)} \ \ \ \ dudv,$

and $\psi\left(  a,c,z\right)\sim z^{-a}$ as $z\to\infty$.
we suppose that $\lambda\to \psi\left(  \frac{\lambda-\mu}{2\lambda},1,\frac{\lambda}{2}(u^2+v^2)\right)$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb C^+_*=\{z\in\Bbb C:\text{Re}(z)>0\} $ and $\mu\in \Bbb C$

Here $\psi$ is the Kummer funtion noted sometimes $U(a,b,c)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function)
Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: The answer should just boil down to "differentiate under the integral sign".  The details should be fairly routine, I would think?  What have you tried?  This might be better suited to math.stackexchange.

Comment: I have found a big problem to do this

Comment: I would try: Morera's theorem.  No need to differentiate, but you do need to interchange the order of integration.

Comment: Yeah. But how to do that

Comment: @GeraldEdgar. How to justify this?

Comment: It suffices to prove juste $T_\lambda$ is a bounded operator